# How to remove leaflet-marker-pane in leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have implemented a pin pointer in my leaflet map.

```
function showLeaflet() {
  var map = L.map("map", {minZoom:1, maxZoom: 1}).setView([66, 384], 1);
  var imageUrl = detailResult.deck[deckFloor].deckplanLarge;
  var imageBounds = [[0, -200], [768, 1024]];
  var cord = (detailResult.deck[deckFloor].markerCordinates).split(',');
  L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
  L.marker([cord[0], cord[1]]).addTo(map).bindPopup(detailResult.title).openPopup();
  map.setMaxBounds(imageBounds);
}
```

How to remove that pin pointer in the following event.

```
map.on('click', function(){
  //remove pointer
});
```

Please help me. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign your marker to variable so that you can use it to remove it from the map using the `removeLayer` method of `L.Map`:

```
var marker = L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(map);

map.on('click', function () {
  map.removeLayer(marker);
});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lTXtnX?p=preview and here is the reference for `L.Map`'s layer methods: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stuff-methods

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the created marker somewhere and then call map.removeLayer with it. I've edited your code below.

```
function showLeaflet() {
  var map = L.map("map", {minZoom:1, maxZoom: 1}).setView([66, 384], 1);
  var imageUrl = detailResult.deck[deckFloor].deckplanLarge;
  var imageBounds = [[0, -200], [768, 1024]];
  var cord = (detailResult.deck[deckFloor].markerCordinates).split(',');
  L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
  var mark = L.marker([cord[0], cord[1]]).addTo(map).bindPopup(detailResult.title).openPopup();
  map.setMaxBounds(imageBounds);

  map.on('click', function(){
      //remove pointer
      map.removeLayer(mark);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much pk. Both solutions are perfectly fine.